# Custom php code error for Woocommerce Elementor Template with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I get an 500 error for the Product template I pasted the shortcode.

I created a Shortcode for displaying an video if user has bought the specific product.

The Video URL is from an ACF field.

```
// Shortcode for Video from ACF
function wpc_elementor_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $product;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) {
    echo get_field('video_tutorial');
    } 
}
add_shortcode( 'purchase_video_tutorial', 'wpc_elementor_shortcode');
```

On Front-End it works but within the elementor builder it shows 500 error if shortcode [purchase_video*_*tutorial] is placed.

Debugging showing error for code above:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null in ..... functions.php:133
```

What do I need to add to the php code to fix this error for elementor pagebuilder?

Comment: add validation for `$product` object.

Comment: How should the code then look? 
Or what do you mean by add validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation means checking that object you are accessing isn't null, like this:

```
if ( $product != null && wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) {
```

Also, the shortcode should **return** the string, not print it

```
echo get_field('video_tutorial');
```

to

```
return get_field('video_tutorial');
```

Also, `wc_customer_bought_product`, first parameter is customer's email

```
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $customer_email = $current_user->email;
    wc_customer_bought_product($customer_email, get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() )
```